# How to use form output in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I just started using symfony and I was wondering where should I write the code for using a form's output in php. Basically I don't know how to use the output of the form to implement it in the code as entry data .

Here's the index.html.twig file

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1> Calculator prim</h1>
    {{  include('_form.html.twig') }}

{% endblock %}
```

And here is the _form.html.twig

```
<form name="Prime" method="post" action="">
    Write the number you want to check <input type="number" name="input"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verifica">
</form>
```

Here is my controller also

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\calculator;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
class ToDoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/todo")
     */
    public function ListAction()
    {

               // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('todo/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

And the php code which will use the number :

```
<?php
    namespace AppBundle\Entity;
    class calculator
    {
        public function calculator($number)
        {

                if($num == 1 || $num == 0)
                {
                    $value = True;
                }
                for ($i = 2; $i <= ($num/2); $i++)
                {
                    if ($num % $i == 0)
                    {
                        $value= True;
                    }
                }
                if (isset($value) && $value)
                {
                    echo "Numarul ". $num . ' nu este prim';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'Numarul '. $num . ' este prim';
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Look up FormType in the Symfony Documentation and use them. They make form handling pretty easy.

Comment: I did, but I can't see where & how are you supposed to process the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quessing you use Symfony 2.8 as it is an LTS.

Ok, first you create a FormType:

```
class MyFormType extends Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('name', 'text')
                ->add('save', 'submit')
                ->setMethod('post');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
         $resolver->setDefaults([
             'data_class' => 'My\Entity';
         ]);
    }
    public function getName() { return 'some_demo_form'; }
}
```

Be aware of the following things:

- with Symfony 3.0, you have to use the fully qualified class name of the field type instead of the shortcut (here "text")

Now register the form type as a service in your `service.yml`

```
my.form.type:
    class: MyFormType
    tags:
      - { name: form.type, alias: some_demo_form }
```

The `alias` *must* be equal to the return value of the `getName()` function of the form type.

And now use the form in your controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller;

class SomeController extends Controller {

    public function showAction(Request $request) {
        $form = $this->createForm('some_demo_form', new My\Entity());

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
             // process data
        }

        return $this->render('template.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ];
    }
}
```

But, really, this is just a breakdown of what's written in the Symfony CookBook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html